# how to use new release of kubernetes as default in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I installed the minikube for local kubernetes development according to article [DevOps-Kubernetes-1-Running-Kubernetes-Locally-via-Minikube](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/DevOps-Kubernetes-1-Running-Kubernetes-Locally-via-Minikube.php)

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- minikube 0.20.0

The default kubernetes for minikube `0.20.0` is `v1.6.4` and I use follow command to use new release `v1.7.0`

```
minikube start  --kubernetes-version v1.7.0
```

How can I set this as default in configuration for minikube ?

So far, if I run `minikube start`, it always starts default `v1.6.4` even the server VM is upgraded to `v1.7.0`

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
...
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", 
GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2017-06-29T23:15:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server 192.168.42.96:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set its default value with:

```
minikube config set kubernetes-version v1.7.0
```

It edits `~/.minikube/config/config.json` and adds:

```
{
    "kubernetes-version": "v1.7.0"
}
```

Check out [Selecting a Kubernetes version](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#selecting-a-kubernetes-version) in the documentation. Check source code [config.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/cmd/minikube/cmd/config/config.go) for reference.

Comment: excellent quick response, it will be better if you can have a url link for the doc,

Comment: I actually found it in the source code :) if you know where's it documented, please share because I couldn't find it.